# Optimization of prime number code

Tags: python, primes

This is my code in python for calculation of sum of prime numbers less than a given number.
What more can I do to optimize it?

```
import math
primes = [2,]                      #primes store the prime numbers



for i in xrange(3,20000,2):                    #i is the test number
    x = math.sqrt(i)
    isprime = True
    for j in primes:               #j is the devider. only primes are used as deviders
        if j <= x:
            if i%j == 0:
                    isprime = False
                    break


    if isprime:
        primes.append(i,)


print sum (primes,)
```

Comment: Replace `if isprime == True:` with `if isprime:`.

Comment: edited the code according to the suggestions..any more suggestions to make it faster?..it is still on the slower side for bigger numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a different algorithm called the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) which will be faster but take more memory. Keep an array of flags, signifying whether each number is a prime or not, and for each new prime set it to zero for all multiples of that prime.

```
N = 10000

# initialize an array of flags
is_prime = [1 for num in xrange(N)]
is_prime[0] = 0 # this is because indexing starts at zero
is_prime[1] = 0 # one is not a prime, but don't mark all of its multiples!

def set_prime(num):
    "num is a prime; set all of its multiples in is_prime to zero"
    for x in xrange(num*2, N, num):
        is_prime[x] = 0

# iterate over all integers up to N and update the is_prime array accordingly
for num in xrange(N):
    if is_prime[num] == 1:
        set_prime(num)

primes = [num for num in xrange(N) if is_prime[num]]
```

You can actually do this for pretty large N if you use an efficient bit array, such as in [this example](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitArrays) (scroll down on the page and you'll find a Sieve of Eratosthenes example).

Comment: this is pretty nice and fast method i see..while i clearly understand the concept and the process i am a bit uncomfortable with the syntax..especially with the initialization line and the last line which forms the list of primes..  unfortunately i dont have any python book with me and i couldnt find the array of flags in the official docs..  could anyone provide me a link for some readings??

Comment: The array of flags in this example is just a list of numbers, where I put `1` if the number is prime and `0` otherwise. As for the syntax of those two lines, search for "list comprehension" to find documentation. In a few words, it is a compact way to write a simple loop which creates a list.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing you could optimize is move the `sqrt` computation outside the inner loop. After all, `i` stays constant through it, so there's no need to recompute `sqrt(i)` every time.

Answer (score 3):

`primes = primes + (i,)` is very expensive. It copies every element on every pass of the loop, converting your elegant dynamic programming solution into an O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm. Use lists instead:

```
primes = [2]
...
    primes.append(i)
```

Also, exit the loop early after passing sqrt(i). And, since you are guaranteed to pass sqrt(i) before running off the end of the list of primes, update the list in-place rather than storing `isprime` for later consumption:

```
...
if j > math.sqrt(i):
    primes.append(i)
    break
if i%j == 0:
    break
...
```

Finally, though this has nothing to do with performance, it is more Pythonic to use range instead of while:

```
for i in range(3, 10000, 2):
    ...
```

Comment: It's O(n^2) anyway, but of course it's better to get rid of the tuples.   Even faster than using `primes.append()` is to compute the sum on the fly and not store the primes at all.

Comment: If he's using python2.x, it would be better to use xrange, too.

Comment: @Sven: if he doesn't store the primes, he's going to have a harder time doing the prime checks.

Comment: @Thomas yes i am using python 2.7..i am not much familiar with xrange though..gonna look it up in the docs..and another thing ..should i always use list instead of tuples? and isnt there any way to add things to tuple?

Comment: @unus sunu: A tuple is an immutable version of a list. You can't change it at all, though you can always make a new one with the change you want.

Comment: Simple answer is: lists are mutable, tuples are not, so you can decide which to use based on that. This does mean you can't add things to a tuple. You could also look up sets if you want, they are more appropriate for your problem.

Comment: @unussunu: Tuples are immutable in Python.  Whenever you want a mutable collection, tuples are not an option.  This doesn't mean you should always use lists instead of tuples.

Comment: Sometimes immutability is a good thing - for example, in the keys of a dictionary.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: With lists instead of tuples, it's O(n^1.5), thanks to the square-root.

Comment: @Marcelo: Only if the loop really exits at the square-root, which neither the OP's original version of the code nor the edited version does.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Yes, you're right. I was thinking in terms of the suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just another code without using any imports:

```
#This will check n, if it is prime, it will return n, if not, it will return 0
def get_primes(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 0
    i = 2
    while True:
        if i * i > n:
            return n
        if n % i == 0:
            return 0
        i += 1

#this will sum up every prime number up to n
def sum_primes(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 0
    i, s = 2, 0
    while i < n:
        s += get_primes(i)
        i += 1
    return s

n = 1000000
print sum_primes(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: removed some silliness while under influence

All brute-force type algorithms for finding prime numbers, no matter how efficient, will become drastically expensive as the upper bound increases.  A heuristic approach to testing for primeness can actually save a lot of computation. Established [divisibility rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) can eliminate most non-primes "at-a-glance".

Comment: This is a very bad idea.  The linked page only shows that containment tests are faster for sets, and the above code does not use such a test.  Most other operations are actually slower for sets.  Most importantly, though, we would lose the order of the primes, so we could not exit the loop upon reaching the square root any more.