# How can I make this summation of primes function faster?

Tags: python, primes

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x<2:
        return False
    elif x%2==0:
        if x==2:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        for i in range(3,x+1,2):
            if x%i==0 and i==x:
                return True
                break
            elif x%i==0:
                return False
                break


def sum_primes(m):
    total=0
    for i in range (3,m,2):
        if is_prime(i):
            total+=i
    return total+2

print sum_primes(2000000)
```

I'm trying to solve one the Project-Euler problems, and this program works but it takes too much time to give me the answer. How can I make it faster guys ?

Comment: have a look at the [Sieve of Erathostenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). You can find some Python implementations [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Python)

Comment: If you're asking how to improve your specific code, take it to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). If you're asking for a faster algorithm, that's been asked hundreds of times, which is why the Related questions sidebar is full of obvious duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked before:

- [python sum of primes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222659/python-sum-of-primes)
- [Optimization of prime number code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019442/optimization-of-prime-number-code)
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37550/summation-of-primes-takes-forever

There are multiple approaches listed in the above links. You might also find this link helpful:

- http://www.parallelpython.com/content/view/17/31/

You might also consider trying to optimize this using Cython.

Answer (score 0):

The Sieve of Eratosthenes enumerates the primes, `sum` accumulates them; first make a list of the number from 2 to *n*, marking them prime, then scan the list in order, stopping at each prime to mark its multiples composite, collecting the primes in order.

```
function sumPrimes(n) # sum of primes less than n
    sum, sieve := 0, makeArray(2..n, True)
    for p from 2 to n
        if sieve[p]
            sum := sum + p
            for i from p*p to n step p
                sieve[i] = False
    return sum
```

I'll leave it to you to translate to Python.

If you're interested in programming with prime numbers, I modestly recommend [this essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog.